# Missing Push Notification Entitlement in Cordova/MobileFirst App

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcode8

I submitted my app to app store and I got the following warning:

```
Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. Xcode 8 does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.
```

I checked into the capabilities section and Push Notification is enabled there. Also I checked into the entitlements file following are values:

[image]

**Entitlements-Debug.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)worklight.group</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Entitlements-Release.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with deleting the App Store distribution profile on your local machine, then re-download and install the distribution profile from the Provisioning Portal.

Make sure your new distribution profile contains `aps-environment` key.

Comment: how do i make sure the new Provisioning Profile have aps-environment key?

Comment: @PrerakTiwari, Make sure you have `aps-environment` key in Entitlements plist file before generating an IPA.